# Split a XWPFRun into multiple runs

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am trying to modify **existing** Word documents by automatically bolding some keywords in them. As an example:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. (1)

would become:

> The quick brown **fox** jumps over the lazy **dog**. (2)

My issue is that (1) is one run and that (2) becomes 5 runs (5 as the period after dog is not bold, but it's a detail). I get the multiple run. It's totally ok.

Question #1:

Is there a way to easily split a run into multiple runs within the same paragraph? I have not managed to do it.

Question #2:

As I did not manage to split a run, I tried to create a new paragraph, but it's really not ideal and add the runs to it. I have managed to duplicate a paragraph entirely and modify the runs in the duplicated paragraph, I keep styling (which is expected) but I lose comments in the duplicated paragraph.

Ideally, I'd like to split the run in place (within the paragraph), but if it's not possible have a better cloner that this:

```
  public static void cloneRun(XWPFRun source, XWPFRun clone) {
    CTRPr rPr = clone.getCTR().isSetRPr()
        ? clone.getCTR().getRPr()
        : clone.getCTR().addNewRPr();
    rPr.set(source.getCTR().getRPr());
    clone.setText(source.getText(0));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In [How do I change color of a particular word document using apache poi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318507/how-do-i-change-color-of-a-particular-word-document-using-apache-poi/40327308#40327308) I have shown an algorithm to split `XWPFRuns` for formatting reasons. This is only for formatting one character and it does not clone the run properties. But the basic is shown. We have to look at the entire paragraph since only there are methods for inserting runs. And we need looping over the run texts character wise since all methods for split into words will lead to problems with punctuation marks while reassembling the words to a paragraph then.

What lacks is a method for cloning the run properties from original run to the new added ones. This could be done by cloning the underlying `w:rPr` element.

Then the whole approach is to go through all runs in paragraph. If we have a run with keyword in it, then split run text into characters. Then go through all characters in that run and buffer them. If the buffered character stream ends with the keyword, then set all chars, which are current buffered, except the keyword, as the text of the actual run. Then insert new run for the formatted keyword and clone the run properties from original run. Set the keyword into the run and do the additional formatting. Then insert a new run for the next characters and also clone the run properties from original run. So on for each run in the paragraph.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Desktop;

public class WordFormatWords {

 static void cloneRunProperties(XWPFRun source, XWPFRun dest) { // clones the underlying w:rPr element
  CTR tRSource = source.getCTR();
  CTRPr rPrSource = tRSource.getRPr();
  if (rPrSource != null) {
   CTRPr rPrDest = (CTRPr)rPrSource.copy();
   CTR tRDest = dest.getCTR();
   tRDest.setRPr(rPrDest);
  }
 }

 static void formatWord(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String keyword, Map<String, String> formats) {
  int runNumber = 0;
  while (runNumber < paragraph.getRuns().size()) { //go through all runs, we cannot use for each since we will possibly insert new runs
   XWPFRun run = paragraph.getRuns().get(runNumber);
   XWPFRun run2 = run;
   String runText = run.getText(0);
   if (runText != null && runText.contains(keyword)) { //if we have a run with keyword in it, then

    // This code part is to manage comment ranges.
    // Do we have commentRangeEnd immediately after the run?
    // If so then remember that in a cursor.
    XmlCursor commentRangeEndCursor = null; 
    XmlCursor cursor = run.getCTR().newCursor();
    cursor.toEndToken();
    if (cursor.hasNextToken()) {
     cursor.toNextToken();
     XmlObject commentRangeEnd = cursor.getObject();
     if (commentRangeEnd != null && commentRangeEnd instanceof CTMarkupRange) {
      commentRangeEndCursor = cursor;
     }
    }

    char[] runChars = runText.toCharArray(); //split run text into characters
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int charNumber = 0; charNumber < runChars.length; charNumber++) { //go through all characters in that run
     sb.append(runChars[charNumber]); //buffer all characters
     runText = sb.toString();
     if (runText.endsWith(keyword)) { //if the bufferend character stream ends with the keyword  
      //set all chars, which are current buffered, except the keyword, as the text of the actual run
      run.setText(runText.substring(0, runText.length() - keyword.length()), 0); 
      run2 = paragraph.insertNewRun(++runNumber); //insert new run for the formatted keyword
      cloneRunProperties(run, run2); // clone the run properties from original run
      run2.setText(keyword, 0); // set the keyword in run
      for (String toSet : formats.keySet()) { // do the additional formatting
       if ("color".equals(toSet)) {
        run2.setColor(formats.get(toSet));
       } else if ("bold".equals(toSet)) {
        run2.setBold(Boolean.valueOf(formats.get(toSet)));
       }
      }
      run2 = paragraph.insertNewRun(++runNumber); //insert a new run for the next characters
      cloneRunProperties(run, run2); // clone the run properties from original run
      run = run2;
      sb = new StringBuffer(); //empty the buffer
     } 
    }
    run.setText(sb.toString(), 0); //set all characters, which are currently buffered, as the text of the actual run

    // This code part is to manage comment ranges.
    // If we had remembered commentRangeEnd, then move this to here now.
    if(commentRangeEndCursor != null) {
     cursor = run.getCTR().newCursor();
     cursor.toEndToken();
     if (cursor.hasNextToken()) {
      cursor.toNextToken();
      commentRangeEndCursor.moveXml(cursor);
     }
     cursor.dispose();
     commentRangeEndCursor.dispose();
    }

   }
   runNumber++;
  }
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("source.docx"));

  String[] keywords = new String[]{"fox", "dog"};
  Map<String, String> formats = new HashMap<String, String>();
  formats.put("bold", "true");
  formats.put("color", "DC143C");

  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : doc.getParagraphs()) { //go through all paragraphs
   for (String keyword : keywords) {
    formatWord(paragraph, keyword, formats);
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

  System.out.println("Done");
  Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("result.docx"));

 }
}
```

This code also takes care about `XML` markup range elements such as `commentRangeEnd` which are immediately after the run's `r` element. Such markup range elements are used to mark start and end of groups of other elements. For example a group of text run elements to those a comment is applied is between `commentRangeStart` and `commentRangeEnd` having same `id`.

If  immediately after the run which  needs to be split follows a `commentRangeEnd`, then we remember that in a cursor. Then after splitting the run we move this `commentRangeEnd` immediately behind the last new inserted run. So comments should stay correct.

Of course even this will have some disadvantages because of the clumsy kind on how `Microsoft Word` stores text in text runs sometimes. There is not the one and only general solution for this when `Microsoft Word` is the source.

Comment: You used the function run.getText(0), but what happens when you have a more complicated Run? For example a Run that contains 3 child nodes (besides the properties node): Text (w:t), Break (w:br) and another Text(w:t) ? I can't find a way in Apache POI to get all child nodes of a Run...