# Change font style in a specific word from docx file using Java Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I'm using Apache POI XWPF to manipulate a docx file, I need to update some words of paragraph and change the font style of it. For updating a single word, it's ok, let's assume that my docx content has the paragraphs bellow:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pretium sodales nisl, ut ornare ligula vehicula vitae. Fusce non magna
> feugiat, sagittis massa at, fermentum nibh. Curabitur auctor leo vitae
> sem tempus, facilisis feugiat orci vestibulum. Mauris molestie sem
> sem, id venenatis arcu congue id. Duis nulla quam, commodo vel dolor
> eget, tempor varius sem. Pellentesque gravida, lectus eu mollis
> pretium, sapien nibh consectetur lacus, non pellentesque lectus ipsum
> ornare eros. Maecenas at magna nunc.
>
> Nulla sagittis aliquam maximus. Cras faucibus id neque sed faucibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et
> ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Phasellus fermentum nulla sed nibh
> varius maximus. Pellentesque dui lorem, luctus non lorem a, blandit
> lacinia arcu. Nunc porttitor erat ut elit hendrerit malesuada. Sed ut
> ex ultricies, rutrum est ut, vulputate orci. Suspendisse vitae diam
> ullamcorper, pulvinar tellus vitae, feugiat ex. In hac habitasse
> platea dictumst. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
> conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin massa lectus, venenatis
> eget massa a, fringilla molestie nisl.

I just do something like it, in this case, the code works, I just want to update the word "ipsum" to "hello world":

```
   File file = new File("document.docx");
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

   XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);

   List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();

    for (XWPFParagraph p: paragraphs) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        for (XWPFRun r: runs) {
           String endText = r.getText(0).replaceFirst("ipsum" , "hello world");
           r.setText(endText,0);
        }
    }

        document.write(new FileOutputStream(uuid + ".docx"));
        fis.close();
        document.close();
```

But if I try to change the text style, like bold, or even change the font color, all of "run" will change, not only the world that I've searched. What I have to do to change the font style only of the word "ipsum" in the example text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have concluded already that the text run is the lowest text entity which may have text formatting. So the need is taking a word or words which shall be formatted differently into their own text runs. Then one can format those text runs.

I have answered this already in [Split a XWPFRun into multiple runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132951/split-a-xwpfrun-into-multiple-runs/57186765). But I will show it again for your special case.

Having the `souce.docx` like this:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Desktop;

public class WordFormatWords {

 static void cloneRunProperties(XWPFRun source, XWPFRun dest) { // clones the underlying w:rPr element
  CTR tRSource = source.getCTR();
  CTRPr rPrSource = tRSource.getRPr();
  if (rPrSource != null) {
   CTRPr rPrDest = (CTRPr)rPrSource.copy();
   CTR tRDest = dest.getCTR();
   tRDest.setRPr(rPrDest);
  }
 }

 static void formatWord(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String keyword, Map<String, String> formats) {
  int runNumber = 0;
  while (runNumber < paragraph.getRuns().size()) { //go through all runs, we cannot use for each since we will possibly insert new runs
   XWPFRun run = paragraph.getRuns().get(runNumber);
   XWPFRun run2 = run;
   String runText = run.getText(0);
   if (runText != null && runText.contains(keyword)) { //if we have a run with keyword in it, then

    char[] runChars = runText.toCharArray(); //split run text into characters
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int charNumber = 0; charNumber < runChars.length; charNumber++) { //go through all characters in that run
     sb.append(runChars[charNumber]); //buffer all characters
     runText = sb.toString();
     if (runText.endsWith(keyword)) { //if the bufferend character stream ends with the keyword  
      //set all chars, which are current buffered, except the keyword, as the text of the actual run
      run.setText(runText.substring(0, runText.length() - keyword.length()), 0); 
      run2 = paragraph.insertNewRun(++runNumber); //insert new run for the formatted keyword
      cloneRunProperties(run, run2); // clone the run properties from original run
      run2.setText(keyword, 0); // set the keyword in run
      for (String toSet : formats.keySet()) { // do the additional formatting
       if ("color".equals(toSet)) {
        run2.setColor(formats.get(toSet));
       } else if ("bold".equals(toSet)) {
        run2.setBold(Boolean.valueOf(formats.get(toSet)));
       }
      }
      run2 = paragraph.insertNewRun(++runNumber); //insert a new run for the next characters
      cloneRunProperties(run, run2); // clone the run properties from original run
      run = run2;
      sb = new StringBuffer(); //empty the buffer
     } 
    }
    run.setText(sb.toString(), 0); //set all characters, which are currently buffered, as the text of the actual run

   }
   runNumber++;
  }
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("source.docx"));

  String[] keywords = new String[]{"ipsum"};
  Map<String, String> formats = new HashMap<String, String>();
  formats.put("bold", "true");
  formats.put("color", "DC143C");

  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : doc.getParagraphs()) { //go through all paragraphs
   for (String keyword : keywords) {
    formatWord(paragraph, keyword, formats);
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("result.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

  System.out.println("Done");
  Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("result.docx"));

 }
}
```

This code leads to a `result.docx` like this:

[image]

Comment: what have I change if I would like to style only the first "ipsum" word found in the text?

Comment: @Murilo Góes de Almeida: You have to understand what the code does. Then you will know where to put a `int foundKeywords` and a `foundKeywords++` as a counter- Then only do split into runs and do the formatting if the counter is less than 1. Hint: you found the keyword `if (runText.endsWith(keyword))`.

Comment: yep I've imagined it, I used a boolean variable and it's worked, I just asked because you could have another approach. thanks again.