# How to search and replace text in a Docx file with mixed formatting using java

Tags: java

I need to search and replace text in docx Word files, using Java, but the text which needs to be replaced has mixed formatting ...

[image]

This doesn't work ...

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.deividasstr</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx-word-replacer</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code

```
import com.xandryex.WordReplacer;

...

File wordFile = new File("<Path to file>");
WordReplacer wordReplacer = new WordReplacer(wordFile);
wordReplacer.replaceWordsInText("appel", "banana");
```

Does anybody have any suggestions? Any change to the formatting is not a problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Apache Poi for this.
Here is similar topic about changing fonts:
[Stackoverflow question 63909413 - change-font-style-in-a-specific-word-from-docx-file-using-java-apache-poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63909413/change-font-style-in-a-specific-word-from-docx-file-using-java-apache-poi)

Here is good introduction to Apache POI if you are not familiar with this library:
[Baeldung Word with Apache POI](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-word-with-apache-poi)