# How to get color of text, word by word, in a Docx file using apache poi java

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to get the color of text, word by word, from a docx file using apache poi. But all I've found is how to set the color.

Answer (score 1):

XPFRun class has a [getColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#getColor--) method. You can use a code similar to shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318507/how-do-i-change-color-of-a-particular-word-document-using-apache-poi), but with getColor instead of setColor.